# Use a variable or a constant in Grafana notification template and alert rule

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

This is a really simple one which I thought should be a few seconds tweek with Grafana, but it turned out to be not.

I want to define a constant variable in the Grafana dashboard. I don't want to read this from any of the data sources, as the data visualizing party has no access to or/and no knowledge about  data sources.

Then I want to use this variable

1. In an alerting rule (I found a few latest documents here and there but they were not clear)
2. In the notification template.

Below is an example.

I want to define a constant variable names "minVal" which is equal to 200.

1. In the Alert Rule, I want to write a rule like ${lastVal} < $minVal, where the "lastVal" is the  last value of a series, which was taken by applying the Math reduce function
2. In the notification template, I want to send the message like "Value has gone below ${minVal}"

Isn't there a really simple way to do this with Grafana?
I am currently using the Grafana version 9.5.12.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible: Grafana [doesn't support variables in alerting rules](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/alerting-rules/create-grafana-managed-rule/#single-and-multi-dimensional-rule)

> **Note:** Grafana does not support alert queries with template variables. More information is available at https://community.grafana.com/t/template-variables-are-not-supported-in-alert-queries-while-setting-up-alert/2514.

To create alerts with dynamic threshold consider storing said threshold in the data source and comparing your actual metrics with it. This way you could include it's value into template like this: `{{ $values.B }}` (if it's stored in the expression `B`).